# Change Data in Vue Component depending on Route

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I need to change the data in a Vue Component depending on the route. For example, when the page Aircraft is loaded I want the data to contain the Aircraft images. If the page Animals is then loaded then I want the data to contain the Animals images.

The website can be seen here: https://test.joebaileyphotography.com/Portfolio

```
Vue.component('subitem', {
      props: ['photo'],
      template: `
        <a :href="photo.img">
            <img :src="photo.img" width="100%" height="auto">
        </a>
      `
    });    
const subitem = {
        data() {
            return { 
                photos: [
                    {img: 'Images/Portfolio/Aircraft/image1.jpg'},
                    {img: 'Images/Portfolio/Aircraft/image1.jpg'},
                    {img: 'Images/Portfolio/Aircraft/image1.jpg'}
                ],
            }
        },
        template: `
            <div>
            <breadcrumbs></breadcrumbs>
            <info></info>
            <div class="portfolio" id="portfolio" data-featherlight-gallery data-featherlight-filter="a:not(.all)">
            <subitem
                v-for="subitem in photos"
                :key="subitem.photo"
                v-bind:photo="subitem">
            </subitem>
            </div>
            </div>
      `
    };
const router = new VueRouter({
        mode: 'history',
        routes: [
            { path: '/Portfolio/:id', component: subitem },
            { path: '/Portfolio', component: item }
        ]
    });
```

Comment: You can check the site you are on with `$route.params.id` and show the photos based on that

Comment: How would I create an if statement within ```const subitem = { data() {```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Vue-router's feature [Dynamic Route Matching](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#dynamic-route-matching) and access the `:id` using `this.$route.params.id` in your component

Or you can [pass route parameters as props](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html).
Just change your route definition to `{ path: '/Portfolio/:id', component: subitem, props: true },` and define `id` prop in your `subitem` component

You can use passed `id` to filter the array  of your photos, for example like this:

```
computed: {
  getPhotosById(id) {
    return this.photos.filter(photo => photo.igm.startsWith(`Images/Portfolio/${id}/`))
  }
}
```

and in the template do `v-for="photos in getPhotosById($route.params.id)"`

Comment: That's great. I'd like to create an array for each page such as Aircraft and Animals etc. I want to use ```v-for="subitem in $route.params.id"``` however this loops through each character and doesn't give the whole word to match up with the data array

Comment: because passed `id` is just value, name of directory. You can use it to filter all photos array. Edited my answer to add an example.....

Comment: Thank you that worked. Just had to change computed to methods though